# Using UIImageView to make a app like iPhone's Photo Galerry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

Please help me !
I make an app like a slide show with back, previous button to change Image one by one. But when I using large image it crash. Now I'm using 64 jpg pics , size~20kb/1pic.

Help me or I die  ! (U can add nick hoangtuanfithou, please)
code like that :

//Init Image Array

```
-(void)InitImageArray1
{
myAnimationImages1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for ( int i = 0; i < 24; i++ )
{
NSAutoreleasePool *poolArray=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"001 (%d)",i];
image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@”jpg”]];

[myAnimationImages1 addObject:image];
[poolArray release];
}

}
```

//Change Image
self.mainImage.image = [self.myAnimationImages1 objectAtIndex:animationImageArrIndex];

Answer (score 0):

see page control sample of apple,or see scrolling madness available at github.